# How to get the data in this example

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the code like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

The first cell of every row is the id (it's unique)
If the input is value of the id, how can I get the value of the third cell in this row

```
Example: input 1 -> output a
         input 2 -> output c
```

How can I do it with Jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `td:last`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UsbpA/)**

```
$('tr').eq(index).find('td:last').text();
```

Comment: eq function is find by index, is there another function to find by text?

Answer (score 3):

### update

You can do something as below

```
var valueSearch = "4";
$('tr').each(function(index){
        if($(this).find('td:first').text()==valueSearch){
            alert($(this).find('td:last').text());
        }

 });
```

Here is a working example at  <kbd>**[live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/9FuM9/2/)**</kbd>

### old answer

```
$('tr').eq("1").find('td:last').text();
```

Is the correct way of doing it.

Here is a live example on <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/9FuM9/)**</kbd>

Comment: no, it isn't the output I want, I want the input 1 and the output is "a",  not the index 1

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer @Adil 's answer to yours!

Comment: @duykhoa cool (y). I too agree that deserves the best answer vote.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
     alert("input "+ $(this + 'td').eq(0).text() + " -> " + $(this + 'td').eq(2).text());
});
```

or try like

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
     alert("input "+ $(this + 'td:first').text() + " -> " + $(this + 'td:last').text());
});
```

Comment: Mine is not working..??I even alerted with single alert statement for all the 'tds' right..??

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript, you can use this

```
var id = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
var value = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[id].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

this exactly what you want.

you can use [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/liyakat/dDYzr/)

And function look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('table tr').each(function() {        

  var str = "input "+ $(this).find('td:first').text() + " -> output " + $(this).find('td:last').text();        
    $("#result").append("</br>"+str);
});
```

});